# Influxdb: Addition of 2 fields doesn't work

Tags: influxdb

I have an influxdb with 2 fields i want to add and then find the max.
I want so use an subquery for the addition of the two fields, but it doesn't work.
Tried this:

```
Select "Field1" + "Field2" as Sum from "testTable" Order by time Desc Limit 10;
```

But the Sum is empty.
Further i only print the fieldson the same way:

```
Select "Field1","Field2" from "testTable" Order by time Desc Limit 10;
```

Thats the result:

> Result

[image]

Where I am doing the mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to do in Flux:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

from(bucket: "yourBucket")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "testTable")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Field1" or r["_field"] == "Field2")
  |> schema.fieldsAsCols()
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with Sum: r.Field1 + r.Field2 }))
  |> max(column: "Sum")
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
I tried a lot and now I used this:  
`from(bucket: "telegraf")
|> range(start:-2m)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "SBC_Aura8")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "SBC RZ3 Total Active Calls" or r._field == "SBC RZ4 Total Active Calls")
|> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: r["SBC RZ3 Total Active Calls"] + r["SBC RZ4 Total Active Calls"] }))`  
now i get again to tables.... What am i doing wrong again?

Comment: Solved:
I nedded to group it, because the agent.host was two different ones.